# How to read twitter feed in json using jackson library

Tags: java, json, jackson

I am trying to create a jNODE object by parsing a JSON file which is in following format:

```
{"delete":{"status":{"id":222318827684372480,"user_id":372364809,"id_str":"222318827684372480","user_id_str":"372364809"}}}
{"delete":{"status":{"id":430870775227117568,"user_id":582666020,"id_str":"430870775227117568","user_id_str":"582666020"}}}
{"delete":{"status":{"id":217335495406010368,"user_id":418026096,"id_str":"217335495406010368","user_id_str":"418026096"}}}
```

While creating jNODE object I am getting an object corresponding to:

```
{"delete":{"status":{"id":222318827684372480,"user_id":372364809,"id_str":"222318827684372480","user_id_str":"372364809"}}}
```

and not rest of the two blocks in the JSON file. Can anyone please help with this?
We have tried to use an iterator to travel but it didnt work. Thanks.

Comment: what if you change that 3-row thing into a valid JSON adding something before and after it? :-)

Comment: Is it not a valid JSON?

Comment: see it yourself http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

Comment: but I agree with you that jackson could at least have warned you of that :-)

Comment: You have *3* objects in a file, one on each line.

Answer (score 0):

Try enclosing the twitter feed in an array and it might be able to parse multiple lines :
[
{"delete":{"status":{"id":222318827684372480,"user_id":372364809,"id_str":"222318827684372480","user_id_str":"372364809"}}}
,
{"delete":{"status":{"id":222318827684372480,"user_id":372364809,"id_str":"222318827684372480","user_id_str":"372364809"}}}
,
{"delete":{"status":{"id":222318827684372480,"user_id":372364809,"id_str":"222318827684372480","user_id_str":"372364809"}}}
]

Comment: The library assumes that there is only one JSON Object as you dont have the enclosing square brackets